# what can be used in C instead of istringstream(in case of C++) in case of parsing?

Tags: c++, c

for example:

```
istringstream ss("hello hi here haha");
string p;
while (iss >> p)
{
    if (p == "hello")
        statement1;
    else if (p == hi)
        statement2;
}
```

here parsing is used so what can b used in c for doing this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `strok`.

Comment: @chris can you put an example code to example..?

Comment: If you ignore a couple small C++ elements, [here's one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: It's actually called `strtok`. I assume @chris simply made a typo. Google should give you plenty of examples and documentation.

Comment: @Code-Guru, Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @chris I didn't at first, either ;-)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/ example right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example code that is your snippet translated to C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char s[] ="hello hi here haha";
  char *tok;
  char *last;
  tok = strtok_r(s, " ", &last);
  while (tok != NULL) {
    if(!strcmp(tok, "hello"))
      statement1;
    else if(!strcmp(tok, "hi"))
      statement2;
    tok = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &last);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Update** I changed the calls of `strtok` to `strtok_r` as recommended by Adam Rosenfield in the comments.

Comment: `strcmp` returns 0 on success. This won't work as intended by OP.

Comment: @KingsIndian Thanks. Typed faster than I thought :) Edited.

Comment: Keep in mind that `strtok` is not thread-safe or reentrant (in the case of signals) due to its reliance on global static data.  On POSIX systems, consider instead using [`strtok_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html).

Comment: and also please explain that strtok is not thread safe how?and what it means?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing something non-trivial, think of using [flexand bison](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
char* ss = "hello hi here hahah";

int i=0;
while (ss[i] != '\0')
{
  while (ss[i] != ' ' && ss[i] != '\0')
    ++i;

  char* p[40];
  memcpy(p,ss,i);

  if (p == "hello")
    statement1;
  else if (p = "hi")
    statement2;
}
```

Comment: much to complicated. `strtok` is what you need. Besides, `p == "hello"` is a pointer comparision. To compare string you use `strcmp`